# Make a transaction to Node 1 without syncing the blockchain on Node 2

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

Is there any way in which I can send a transaction to a contract deployed on Node 1 from Node 2 without syncing the entire blockchain on Node 2. I basically want to access the Node 2 without having the blocks stored on Node 2.

It should be like a 'partial' blockchain.

Comment: This is only possible if you sync node 2 in light mode.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to do it? I have been trying it for a long time, but it hasn't worked. Links to any helpful resources would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is against the purpose of blockchain.

The principle of blockchain is that every one knows everything so that no one can change what happened.